# Is bundled data global or activity-dependant?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I want to pass some bundled data from activity A to C. The flaw looks like this:

"A calls activity B
B calls activity C"

Right now, my B activity catches the bundled data, packs it into its own intent and then passes it to the activity C.

Is there a way to fetch bundled data in C without passing it explicitly via B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Activity dependent.  But yes, you can always use any of these for it

- A singleton pattern to share the date across multiple non-consecutive activities.
- A shared preference.
- An external storage
- Entry into db.

The below link can give you some more detail:

http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3

Comment: Any link would be appreciated?!

Comment: Added a link hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep that data in static variables in some class that holds your custom application context.

Comment: And the static class inherits which class...? I mean in the static class definition.